# Asynchronously scrape fabric information

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, async-await

This is my first asyncio/aiohttp web scraper. I am trying to wrap my head around Python's asyncio/aiohttp libs these days and I am not sure if I fully understand it or not yet. So I'd like have some constructive enhancement reviews here.

I'm scraping [Spoonflower](https://www.spoonflower.com/), which contains some public API's for design data and pricing per fabric type data. My challenge was to get the design name, creator name and price of each design as per fabric type. Design name and creator name comes from this endpoint

> https://pythias.spoonflower.com/search/v1/designs?lang=en&page_offset=0&sort=bestSelling&product=Fabric&forSale=true&showMatureContent=false&page_locale=en

and other pricing per fabric type data coming from this endpoint.

> [https://api-gateway.spoonflower.com/alpenrose/pricing/fabrics/FABRIC_'+%20fab_type%20+'?quantity=1&shipping_country=PK&currency=EUR&measurement_system=METRIC&design_id='%20str(item['designId'])%20'&page_locale=en](https://api-gateway.spoonflower.com/alpenrose/pricing/fabrics/FABRIC_%27+%20fab_type%20+%27?quantity=1&shipping_country=PK&currency=EUR&measurement_system=METRIC&design_id=%27%20str(item%5B%27designId%27%5D)%20%27&page_locale=en)

Each page has 84 items and 24 fabric types. I'm first getting all the names of the fabric types and storing in a list. I can loop through it and change the url dynamically then extracting `designName` and `screenName` from design page and finally extracting the price data.

Here is my code:

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from collections import OrderedDict


item_endpoint = 'https://pythias.spoonflower.com/search/v1/designs?lang=en&page_offset=0&sort=bestSelling&product=Fabric&forSale=true&showMatureContent=false&page_locale=en'

def get_fabric_names():
    res = requests.get('https://www.spoonflower.com/spoonflower_fabrics')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
    fabrics = [fabric.find('h2').text.strip() for fabric in soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'product_detail medium_text'})]
    fabric = [("_".join(fab.upper().replace(u"\u2122", '').split())) for fab in fabrics]
    for index in range(len(fabric)):
        if 'COTTON_LAWN_(BETA)' in fabric[index]:
            fabric[index] = 'COTTON_LAWN_APPAREL'
        elif 'COTTON_POPLIN' in fabric[index]:
            fabric[index] = 'COTTON_POPLIN_BRAVA'
        elif 'ORGANIC_COTTON_KNIT' in fabric[index]:
            fabric[index] = 'ORGANIC_COTTON_KNIT_PRIMA'
        elif 'PERFORMANCE_PIQUÉ' in fabric[index]:
            fabric[index] = 'PERFORMANCE_PIQUE'
        elif 'CYPRESS_COTTON' in fabric[index]:
            fabric[index] = 'CYPRESS_COTTON_BRAVA'
    return fabric

async def fetch_design_endpoint(session, design_url):
    async with session.get(design_url) as response:
        extracting_endpoint = await response.text()
        _json_object = json.loads(extracting_endpoint)
        return _json_object['page_results']

async def fetch_pricing_data(session, pricing_endpoint):
    async with session.get(pricing_endpoint) as response:
        data_endpoint = await response.text()
        _json_object = json.loads(data_endpoint)
        items_dict = OrderedDict()
        for item in await fetch_design_endpoint(session, item_endpoint):
            designName = item['name']
            screenName = item['user']['screenName']
            fabric_name = _json_object['data']['fabric_code']
            try:
                test_swatch_meter = _json_object['data']['pricing']['TEST_SWATCH_METER']['price']
            except:
                test_swatch_meter = 'N/A'
            try:
                fat_quarter_meter = _json_object['data']['pricing']['FAT_QUARTER_METER']['price']
            except:
                fat_quarter_meter = 'N/A'
            try:
                meter = _json_object['data']['pricing']['METER']['price']
            except:
                meter = 'N/A'

            
            #print(designName, screenName, fabric_name, test_swatch_meter,fat_quarter_meter, meter)

            if (designName, screenName) not in items_dict.keys():
                items_dict[(designName, screenName)] = {}
            itemCount = len(items_dict[(designName, screenName)].values()) / 4
            return items_dict[(designName, screenName)].update({'fabric_name_%02d' %itemCount: fabric_name,
            'test_swatch_meter_%02d' %itemCount: test_swatch_meter,
            'fat_quarter_meter_%02d' %itemCount: fat_quarter_meter,
            'meter_%02d' %itemCount: meter})
                

        

async def main():
    tasks = []
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        fabric_type = get_fabric_names()
        design_page = await fetch_design_endpoint(session, item_endpoint)
        for item in design_page:
            for fab_type in fabric_type[0:-3]:
                pricing_url = 'https://api-gateway.spoonflower.com/alpenrose/pricing/fabrics/FABRIC_'+ fab_type +'?quantity=1&shipping_country=PK&currency=EUR&measurement_system=METRIC&design_id='+str(item['designId'])+'&page_locale=en'
                print(pricing_url)
                await fetch_pricing_data(session, pricing_url)

                tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(
                    fetch_pricing_data(session, pricing_url)

                    )
                )

        content = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        return content
results = asyncio.run(main())
print(results)
```

Any ideas and suggestions are welcome to make this scraper more Pythonic and smart.

Comment: Is there public documentation available for the site's API? If there is, could you add a link to it?

Comment: I don't think so at least I am not aware of that if their public documentation is available or not.

Comment: @dougj I would also recommend looking into [urllib.parse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html) as it makes parsing and maintaining urls a bit cleaner.

Comment: Please don't update the question, especially the code in the question after it has an answer. Everyone must be able to see the same question the person that wrote the answer saw. If you want to make changes based on the answer ask a follow up question that links to this question.

Answer (score 10):

While you *can* put request parameters in the URI directly, it's usually neater to pass those using the `params` argument of `session.get`. So for example `pricing_url` could just be `"https://api-gateway.spoonflower.com/alpenrose/pricing/fabrics/FABRIC_" + fab_type` and you could pass the rest as `params={"quantity": 1, "shipping_country": "PK", "currency": "EUR", ...})`. That's usually more readable.

`get_fabric_names` is very different than the others - it uses `requests` rather than `aiohttp` and it hardcodes its URI instead of taking it as a parameter. I'm not saying that's a *problem*, but it feels a bit inconsistent.

`aiohttp` has JSON parsing built into its responses. If all you're going to do with `some_response.text()` is pass it to `json.loads`, you may be better off just calling `some_response.json()` and drop the `data_endpoint` and `extracting_endpoint` variables.

I find it a bit strange that, even though there's a public-facing API, the way you obtain a list of fabric names is by extracting it from an HTML document. Now, I don't know Spoonflower's API, maybe that's the best (or only) way available, but it *feels* like there should be a better option.

Is the `return` from `fetch_pricing_data` really supposed to be *inside* the loop? It doesn't look like there are any `continue`s or other ways to skip it, so the loop will only run for one iteration, right? It seems a bit strange to use a loop in that case.

The output format of `fetch_pricing_data` is a bit unusual. If I'm understanding this correctly, each fabric type gets a `dict` shaped like:

```
# I have no idea what actual values you'll work with, so I'm making some up
{
    'fabric_name_00': 'some name',
    'fabric_name_01': 'some other name',
    'test_swatch_meter_00': 20,
    'test_swatch_meter_01': 20,
    'fat_quarter_meter_00': 25,
    'fat_quarter_meter_01': 25,
    'meter_00': 5,
    'meter_01': 6,
    ...: ...
}
```

...which seems really awkward to me. If each number will contain all of those (which you seem to assume), I feel like an easier-to-work-with format could be:

```
[
    {
        'fabric_name': 'some name',
        'test_swatch_meter': 20,
        'fat_quarter_meter': 25,
        'meter': 5
    },
    {
        'fabric_name': 'some other name',
        'test_swatch_meter': 20,
        'fat_quarter_meter': 25,
        'meter': 6
    },
    ...
]
```

The manual replacement of fabric names in `get_fabric_names` feels a bit clunky. Now, depending on how the API is designed that might be the only way to actually get those fabric IDs, but even if that's the case I'd think it best to keep the list of replacements elsewhere - it looks like the kind of thing that might need changing over time, so putting it in a variable somewhere or even in a separate data file might make sense.

It's not at all clear why you skip the last 3 values in `fabric_type`. If it's because they aren't fabric types, I think it should be `get_fabric_names`'s responsibility to not return them in the first place.

Finally, some nitpicks about variable names:

- `fabric` is a bit of a weird name considering it's a list of *multiple* fabrics. Maybe `fabric_names`? Or maybe call it `fabrics` and rename the existing `fabrics` to something like `fabric_headers`? Or both!
- Same for `fabric_type` in `main` - why not `fabric_types`?
- Most of your variables called `*_endpoint` are URIs you can send requests to. Clear and consistent. But `data_endpoint` and `extracting_endpoint` are responses to queries, which is mildly confusing on its own and also goes against the convention you establish.
- The name `items_dict` is a bit redundant. Isn't `items` enough?
- You seem to pretty consistently use `this_casing_scheme` for variable names (as is conventional in Python), except for `designName`, `screenName` and `itemCount`. You might want to rename those for consistency
- Why the leading `_` in `_json_object`?

Comment: Thanks for your constructive feedback I will improve it soon.

Comment: fabric_names using requests because it's only job to get the names of all the fabric from only page so I thought it doesn't make much sense to make it async.

Comment: Actually there were 27 fabric types and the last 3 wasn't associated to any other designs if I iterate over those it gives weird results so that's why I slice it till [0:-3]

Answer (score 6):

Something not included in the other answers:

These two lines in your `main` function mean that you request and parse each page twice. It also means your code is not really async, because you loop over all fabrics and just `await` each of them. You should be able to just remove the first one.

```
await fetch_pricing_data(session, pricing_url)
tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(fetch_pricing_data(session, pricing_url))
```

In addition, you could spawn async tasks in that function instead of the simple `for` loop you currently have:

```
for item in await fetch_design_endpoint(session, item_endpoint)
```

This will speed up your code by quite a lot, probably,  once you have fixed the return value of that function to be outside the loop.

However, your function `fetch_design_endpoint` does not actually depend on anything specific in `fetch_pricing_data`. This is either a bug (did you want to change the URL?) or you could retrieve the results only once.

Comment: Yeah it makes much more sense.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not too experienced with asyncio, but I have a couple of minor observations about your program.

It is a code smell in modern Python to use an int to index over an array.  Instead of

```
for index in range(len(fabric)):
```

You could say

```
for fabric_type in fabric:
```

Another observation in that you are using naked except blocks instead of catching "KeyError" explicitly.  If you do so you save the reader some mental effort going back to see why you would be expecting a problem to be raised.

Comment: The loop over the index actually uses the index to modify the array. To avoid the `range(len)` approach here you'd have to use `enumerate` as in `for index, fabric_type in enumerate(fabric):`

Comment: Actually I want in place changes to modify the list that is why I have to use range(len)

Comment: @dougj not quite. In python you can iterate over the index and the value at the same time using `enumerate`. For example: `for index, value in enumerate(['zero', 'one', 'two'])` would return a tuple like this at each iteration: `(0, 'zero',)`, `(1, 'one',)`, `(2, 'two',)`.

Comment: Ah!Nice to know that I will give it a try.